# Detecting Data Changes with lightning:recordform

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-record-form

how can one bind onchange event handlers to the fields of the `lightning:recordform` component?

component.cmp

```
   <aura:attribute name="fieldsArray" type="String[]"
   default="['Subject','Description']" />

    <lightning:recordForm aura:id="recordForm"
           objectApiName="Case"
           fields="{!v.fieldsArray}"               
           layout="Full"
           mode="Edit"
           onsubmit="{!v.submit}"
           />
```

if i were to use `lightning:recordEditForm` component, i would simply add it in my field component as follows:

```
<lightning:inputField fieldName="Subject" onchange="{!c.itemsChange}"/>
```

the lack of documentation on this component doesnt make this easy.

Comment: What happens when you put a change event handler on `v.fieldsArray` and change a value in an input? Any change event handled?

Comment: nothing , since the attribute is for the fieldset itself, which doesnt change =(

Comment: There's a hidden `fields` attribute on recordEditForm that you can inspect to retrieve field values. Since this component supposedly builds on top of recordEditForm I had thought maybe you can inspect it somehow.

Comment: Actually, if you `component.find("recordForm").get("v.fields")` does it return more than your original list of strings? I'm out of ideas after that.

Comment: have you tried put `onchange`   in `lightning:recordForm` then you can get a changed value using  `event.getParams()` and getting fields `event.getSource().get("v.fields)`

Comment: @glls I'm imagining your use case is something along the lines of updating one field when another changes? Would you be able to expand on what functionality you're trying to build?

Comment: Putting onchange on the recordForm does call the function specified, with an event parameter "value": <<new field value>>. Whilst event.getSource().get("v.fields") does give you the list of fields on the component, it doesn't tell you the field the value change occurred on. In addition to this I can't see any way to get a handle on a field value within the component to update it. You can modify values in onsubmit event in the manner documented here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/225747, and I suspect you might be able to modify field values in the "record" param in onload().

Comment: the component is not mature enough nor is it well documented, so i went back to using lightning:recordeditform component. I will wait some time before attemtping anything with it

Comment: @glls did you found a solution to get an information of changed values from recordForm, or at least to get all fields from the record onChange event?

Comment: nope - except use lightning:recordEditForm