# Populating ParentWorkOrder field in <lightning:recordEditForm>

Tags: lightning-aura-components

...I have tried EVERYTHING and cant seem to find what I am doing wrong. I am trying  to prepopulate ParentWorkOrder on a new workorder lightning record create here is my code. I am new to writing components so please help.

```
<aura:component access="global">

    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="parentId" type="String" default="0WO54000000D0zw"/>
    <aura:attribute name="ONOFF" type="string" default="false"/>

    <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordEditForm"
                           recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                           objectApiName="WorkOrder"
                           onsubmit="{!c.handleOnSubmit}"
                           onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}">        
        <lightning:messages />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Service_Filters_Needed__c" />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Is_there_an_issue_with_equipment__c" />
        <lightning:outputField fieldName="ParentWorkOrder" aura:id="parentWOLookup" value=""/>
        <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" type="submit" label="submit" />
    </lightning:recordEditForm> 
</aura:component>
```

controller

```
({

    handleSuccess : function(component, event, helper) {
        var payload = event.getParams().response;
        console.log(payload.id);
        component.set("v.ONOFF", true);     
    },


    handleOnSubmit : function(component, event, helper) {
      var fields = event.getParam("fields");
      fields["ParentWorkOrder"] = component.get("v.parentId");
    }
})
```

Comment: Please give your questions a clear, descriptive title. "PLEASE HELP ME" in all caps does not help guide the relevant expertise to your question.

Comment: it would be user error on my part, gotr it working now

Answer (score 1):

I haven't really tried it out, but based on what is mentioned in the documentation for [`lightning:recordEditForm`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation):

> If you capture the submit event and submit the form programmatically, use `event.preventDefault()` to cancel the default behavior of the event.

You will need to modify your `handleOnSubmit` JS function to something as below. You can refer more on the example as in the documentation on these behaviors.

```
handleOnSubmit : function(component, event, helper) {
    // add this in your function to stop submitting the form
    event.preventDefault(); 

    var fields = event.getParam("fields");

    // notice how ParentWorkOrder field is being referred
    fields.ParentWorkOrder = component.get("v.parentId"); 

    // submit the form now
    component.find('recordEditForm').submit(fields);
}
```

Comment: Issue is that onsuccess is not called at all -- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/225747/lightningrecordeditform-set-or-modify-field-values-onsubmit/225922#comment362951_225922

Comment: @kurunve, possibly could be an issue. The details here are based on how it is mentioned in the documentation. I haven't really tried it out myself.