# Get values and fields from "lightning:recordForm" component

Tags: lightning, aura, lightning-record-form

I'm creating a form using "**lightning:recordForm**". I put the object's Id, the object's type and what fields should be viewed.

```
<lightning:recordForm aura:id="myObject"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      objectApiName="{!v.objType}"
                      fields="{!v.fieldsObject}"
                      columns="2"
                      mode="edit"
                      onsubmit="{!c.saveObject}" />
```

Please, could anyone tell me if there is any way for me to retrieve the information from the "fields" parameter, and their respective values, from "aura: id"?

I want to do this procedure before the user submits the form. Because before submitting I have another procedure, so I want to do the validation first, whether the field is required or not.

Comment: see if this is helpful https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/225747/lightningrecordeditform-set-or-modify-field-values-onsubmit

Answer (score 0):

For input validation you can use the `onsubmit` callback to do validation and stop submit if data is not valid, if you need to do validation while the user is typing then you will to use [lightning:inputField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputField/documentation) and [lightning:recordEditForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation).

Using `lightning:recordEditForm` and `lightning:inputField` you can set input as  "required" or "readonly" independently from the Object or do more complex validation using the `onchange` event of the `aura:attribute` tied to a `lightning:inputField`.

See: [Detecting Data Changes with Change Handlers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_data_change.htm)